# How to prevent setState((){}); in flutter?

Tags: flutter-layout, setstate, flutter-form-builder

` setState(() {
//how to prevent set state in here
rating = aaa;
});

```
onChanged: (aaa) {
   setState(() {
    rating = aaa;
   });
},`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ValueListenableBuilder instead of setState.
Eg: If rating is type of int. So, you can make a type ValueNoifier of type int & listen to its changes.

```
 ValueNotifier<int> rating = ValueNotifier<int>(0);

//......change the value of rating in the onChanged:

 onChanged(aaa){
  rating.value = aaa;
 }

// .... Wrap your Widget with Listenable builder to listen to the change in rating.

ValueListenableBuilder(
valueListenable: rating,
builder : (context, value, child) => SomeWidget(......)
)
```

Comment: You mean I must wrap checkbox widget

Comment: Yes. Just Wrap your widget with the listenable builder. If you need to see an example, I have two gists for comparison:

setState  : 
https://gist.github.com/thecaptainXgod/7eae0efa44bffff899810250a7f06b5d

ValueNotifier : https://gist.github.com/thecaptainXgod/29696ea733ad7ddde5712fe7e07ac3a5